# Using a permanent background image with Flutter

Tags: image, user-interface, flutter

I am working on an app with a 2 tab view and want a permanent background image while being able to swipe or navigate between the 2 tabs. Here is the code for the widget:

```
class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyTabsState createState() => new MyTabsState();
}

class MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Divot', style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Pacifico')),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        bottom: new TabBar(
          controller: controller,
            tabs: <Tab>[
              new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.golf_course)),
              new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.account_circle)),
            ]),
      ),
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("image"), fit: BoxFit.fill,),
            ),
          ),
          new TabBarView(
            controller: controller,
              children: <Widget>[
                new second.GameMenu(),
                new third.MyProfilePage(),
              ],
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I get no errors, but I get a white background on the first tab, and my AssetImage background on the second tab. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but just in case...

I got the effect you want by using a Container as the Scaffold body: and making TabBarView the child: of the Container. You can then use...

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image:
                  AssetImage("some image path"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                  Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4), BlendMode.dstATop),
```

to create the background which appears on each tab view :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Android this would have been much easier, all you had to do was set the background property in the XML file and its that simple.

In flutter i would suggest in the `body` property of the Scaffold, in the `TabBarView` children you might try to pass Widgets with backgrounds. Or try setting the `backgroundColor` property of most of your widgets to `Colors.transparent`.